# Regex to find multiple matches in list

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to use regex to find the processor models from a list so it would return with both "Intel Core i7-4710HQ" and "AMD A10-5745M"
 What i was using to retrieve only the intel models was "**/Intel(.*)/**" but how would i retrieve both models.

Example of the list is:

- DVD+/-RW
- DDR3L SDRAM (2 DIMM)
- **Intel Core i7-4710HQ**
- 12 GB
- **AMD A10-5745M**
- 128GB SSD

What would be the correct expression to use to retrieve such info from a list?

Comment: Just see if the string starts with "Intel", or "AMD", or any other processor manufacturer. That won't be perfect but meh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you processor models are preceded by their manufacturer name, then you could do something like so: `(((Intel)|(AMD)).+)`. An example of the regular expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/wW5sD7/1).

Alternatively, you depending on the language you are using you could see if the language provides a `startsWith` or `indexOf`.

Comment: I appreciate your response. That helps alot! Thank you kindly.

Comment: Why are you capturing the manufacturer? Just; `INTEL|AMD` should be enough, or at worst `^(INTEL|AMD).+`

Comment: @Bohemian: From what I understood, the OP wants the full name of the processor.

Comment: That's just the whole match (group zero) - no need to capture anything

Comment: @Bohemian: I understand what you mean now. When using the | I tend to put whatever it is I am looking for into their groups. I find it easier to follow, something like `(value1)|(value2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use anchors to get whole string matches with a multiline option:

`^((?:Intel|AMD).*)$`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM1qI2/2).